# Why didn't Yosef tell pharaoh to repent?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yosef

In parshas Miketz, Yosef interprets pharaoh's dream and offers his advice on how to help the dire future situation.

However, his advice is purely practical, seemingly just a way to avoid Hashem's judgement.
This seems more like the Dor Haflaga building a tower to avoid future floods when the sky cracks open, rather than a prophet of Hashem who would admonish those to be affected to repent, like what Yona did with Ninvei.

Why would Yosef act in this way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142061/discussion-on-question-by-user6591-why-didnt-yosef-tell-pharaoh-to-repent).

Comment: it was Yosef's ability to interpret Paro's dream that made Yosef appear wise in his eyes but perhaps if he added additional things not related to the dream directly then he would have dismissed him as he had all of the "wise" men in Egypt. It seems to me that the way Hashem orchestrated this point was for Yosef to have a way to redeem hiself. What then would be of this opportunity if at the same time he angered Paro and got sent back to jail? It would have meant he was not in a position to help b'ne yisroel when they had to settle in Egypt and perhaps the suffering would have been longer

Answer (score 2):

Once again, I would have put this in a comment, but I only have 49 reputation points, and need just one more to comment!
Anyway, in response to a comment above, since when is dream interpretation Nevuah? Besides, this doesn't answer why Yosef couldn't have simply told Pharoah simple personal advice to repent, indeed not as a part of the interpretation of the dream.
Personally, this question opened up my mind to a really cool observation. We know the Midrash says that the King of Nineveh in Sefer Yonah, was also Pharaoh (I believe it's a Machlokes if it was the same Pharaoh. See Rashi on Shemos 1:8, unless the Pharaoh changed again during the Ten Plagues, which I think might have been the case.) Either way though, we find there too that Yonah specifically did not want to tell the King to repent because of negative repercussions for the Jews. I wonder if there may be a real repetition/connection between that story, and here, Yosef specifically trying to give Pharaoh an alternative method of dealing with the punishments, other than repentance. I mean imagine if Pharoah and Egypt would have indeed repented. Maybe that would have prevented Klal Yisroel's entire future i.e., Galus & Yetzias Mitzrayim, which may very well have been a pre-requisite to receiving the Torah! Gut Shabbos, A Gut Chodesh, and A Freilichen Chanukah!

Comment: But what did paroh do to need to repent? And when was yosef sent with the job of telling him to repent? Yonah was sent.

Comment: @rosends On the contrary, Yonah was sent by God and STILL tried to refrain! Yosef who wasn't sent by God, why on earth would he go ahead and tell Pharaoh on his own? As for what Pharaoh did wrong, Is Egypt not recognizing the true God, not good enough of a reason? Besides, I believe it's clear that they were a very sinful nation! Prohibitions in the Torah refer to "the way they did in Egypt"...

Comment: He wasn't sent, so why would he be expected to do the mission? Avraham was there and saw a bad act and yet he didn't preach repentance. If it isn't the mission, then why expect it to be done? Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but Yonah was told to do something and eventually he does it. Yosef simply wasn't told to do that. Hashem never tells Yosef that the behavior of the Egyptians is wickedness requiring divine retribution if there is no repentance. And what are you seeing as "punishment"? There were years of plenty first, and Hashem sent Yosef to help out.

Comment: I agree that he did not need to preach repentance, but why didn't he do so from his own will to bring repentance to the world? This is what I believe was the original question. I'm trying to explain why he may have specifically wanted them to NOT repent. (I agree this whole idea is hard to understand theologically.) I don't understand what you said about Avraham can you clarify please?

Comment: We have no evidence that Yosef saw any wrong doing by Paroh. We know that Avraham DID see wrong doing, but he didn't preach repentance.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hear both things you're saying, and I don't know how much I agree with either, but now I understand where you're coming from. I'll quickly answer that Yosef PROBABLY WAS aware of what was going on in Egypt at the time, judging by the time he spent there, and Yosef was probably in a more appropriate situation to tell Pharaoh that his Country needs to repent. However, I still think your points are valid and this all definitely needs more careful consideration.

Comment: @AYALTAAROG The interperetations of dreams, especially in this story, is through nevuah. One needs not look farther then parshas Miketz, perek מא pasuk טז. The meforshim further expound on this.

Comment: @KovyJacob You're right! Same goes for you @rosends! I didn't see all the Meforshim so I don't know if necessarily all the Meforshim would agree, but in fact the Chasam Sofer himself also writes clearly that it was through Nevuah. BTW, what is the protocol with editing answers to reflect newly revealed information? Are you supposed to even when it takes away the context from the comments?

Comment: 41:16 Yosef proclaimed his interpretations weren't simply that of a dream interpreter, rather he was relating Hashem's message. It's debated in the Mefarshim if he meant these dreams would become reality based on the interpretation (see Rashbam and Or HaChaim) but certainly the simple reading is that he was claiming to be giving a message from Hashem, see the Targums who both say the expression מן קדם השם, that's the term they use when Hashem is really talking.

Comment: @Harel13 I was very stressed out and it was completely unwarranted for me to be so rude! I sincerely feel very bad and strongly regret my crazy response to what was obviously a hasty misreading of mine. Praised are you for doing your selfless work of helping organize and spread Torah on this website for no personal benefit! Anger is terrible and I am very sorry!

Comment: @AYALTAAROG I forgive you. Thank you for the apology. I'll delete my previous comments here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to be EXTREMELY careful about how you speak about Yosef hatzaddik. He was a tzaddik, a navi, and you should be very careful to ask any question from the point o view of your lack of understanding. Comparing Yosef to the dor haflaga, chas veshalom, is something you don't want to do.

That being said, lets first talk about the interpereting of the dream. The interpretation was not Yosef Hatzaddik's own interpretation, it was a nevuah (I have personally seen this brought down in Shiurei R' Shlomo Volbe and the Griz Al Hatorah). So the interpretation was not an interperetation per se, it was a nevuah.

So now, the question we are left with is why did Yosef Hatzaddik choose to give practical advice on how to prepare for the upcoming famine, instead of telling Paroh to do teshuvah?

For this, lets take a step back and look at the whole famine. This was orchestrated by Hashem for the purpose of bringing the shevatim, and through that the rest of bnei yisrael, to Egyptians. I saw, I forgot where, that through this whole story Yosef knew through nevuah that this was all being orchestrated as a fulfillment of his dreams that he had had (with the whear and stars bowing), and that is why Yosef Hatzaddik did what he did, at any point. So that would presumably answer your question.

Comment: I do not see why you considered his question disrespectful.

Comment: @MichoelR You don't see how comparing what Yosef Hatzaddik said to the Dor Haflaga is disrespectful?

Comment: He understands that Yosef was good, the Dor Haflaga bad, and therefore he asks why he sees a similarity in their actions.

Comment: @MichoelR If one sees a between Yosef Hatzaddik and the Dor Haflaga, the question shouldn't be why Yosef Hatzaddik acted the way he did, the question should be why they seem to think there is a similarity, and that that is an okay comparison to make.

Comment: I think he just left out a frum phrase you expected, like "ח"ו", or "of course there is no comparison"... Historically and today, different communities and gedolim had different customs on whether to add those phrases. You are from a community where they are required, as am I. But you would have no problem finding a question like that in your Mikraos Gedolos.

Comment: @MichoelR No, if I saw Mikraos Gedolos compare the advice Yosef Hatzaddik gave to the Dor Haflaga, I would be disturbed. Saying 'chas veshalom' after something you mean doesn't make it better.

Comment: We are allowed to try to understand the Torah. The question is a reasonable one, and you should think about what would make you be comfortable w the wording. The whole thing you said, "you have to be EXTREMELY careful..." Just open a Mikraos Gedolos to these parshiyos, and see any question they are asking about what the shevatim and Yosef did. Generally they add no disclaimers, no extreme care; they just want to understand.

Comment: @Koby Jacob I think I would add that I think the frum community would be _more_ effective in working with non-religious Jews, if they were more willing to be honest with how some parts of the Torah appear at face value. If you start a discussion of Yosef and his brothers with, "Of course they were tzaddikim beyond our understanding..." you are going to find it hard to deal with someone who says, "Huh? They sound way worse than us. Did *you* ever sell your brother into slavery, or plan to leave him in a pit to die?" I had such an email exchange recently, very interesting.

Comment: @MichoelR To quote what someone said on here recently, "You want to being them closer to the Torah, not the Torah closer to them". We can all admit that this parsha is very shver FOR US TO UNDERSTAND, but that is FOR US TO UNDERSTAND. The shevatim were tzaddikim gemurim. One can explain that although this parsha is hard for us to understand, we have to first realize who the shevatim were - the shivtei ka. Using sheker to entice someone to yiddishkeit is NOT a good thing.

Comment: @MichoelR The honest truth about the certain parts of the Torah you refer to is that is a chisaron is US that we find it hard to understand. I can understand why one would learn this from the perspective of the shevatim are bad, but that is absolutely false. Sheker vichazav. It is a chisaron in our daas, the fact that our daas is not aligned with the Torah, that we find these things hard to understand.

Comment: I don't think it's sheker at all. A five-year-old reads Chumash, and the way it appears to a five-year-old is part of Hashem's Torah. I think it is a mistake to cut yourself off from taking the words seriously. I didn't say my friend in the email is right. I said he is taking the Torah seriously and trying to understand it, and we need to do the same. You seem to be surrendering before you start: "I know it looks bad, but..." I believe that if you and I would take the Torah *seriously*, we would find the right way to understand it that does not look bad at all.

Comment: Do you not see that of the two of us, my approach is the one that trusts Hashem and the Torah, but according to your approach, the right way is to pretend that we're reading it and really only read Chazal's comments on it? How can we bring *anyone* closer to the Torah if we don't ourselves believe it says anything we can read? [I feel that RSR Hirsch takes this obligation very seriously.]

Comment: @MichoelR "A five-year-old reads Chumash, and the way it appears to a five-year-old is part of Hashem's Torah" - what in the world does that mean? Are 5 year old unable to be wrong? One can misunderstand the Torah, and one misunderstanding the Torah isn't part of the Torah - its an incorrect understanding of the Torah. "I didn't say my friend in the email is right. I said he is taking the Torah seriously and trying to understand it, and we need to do the same" - I never said he is not trying to understand. However, in his effort to understand, he is making a mistake which leads to 1/2

Comment: @MichoelR 2/2 understanding incorrectly, and questions which would not be asked if one properly understood. " You seem to be surrendering before you start: "I know it looks bad, but..."" - I am not surrendering, I am stating to one with the wrong, and may I say, gaavadig mindset that fails to recognize who the shevatim are and who they are, one might come to make an understandable, yet incorrect, mistake.

Comment: @MichoelR 3/2 "I believe that if you and I would take the Torah seriously, we would find the right way to understand it that does not look bad at all" - if it looks bad, it is a chisaron in one's understanding. Not, chas veshalom, in what is written. If one thinks too much of themselves, too little of the shevatim, or maybe just doesn't think much at all, they will come to multitudes of incorrect understandings.

Comment: "Do you not see that of the two of us, my approach is the one that trusts Hashem and the Torah, but according to your approach, the right way is to pretend that we're reading it and really only read Chazal's comments on it?" - Chas veshalom! Are you insinuating that Chazal is, chas veshalom, seperate from the Torah?! I do not know what community you claim to be from, but that is a totally treif hashkafa. The chachamim before us clearly explained the Torah to us. Don't pretend to have a moral high ground that trusts Hashem, whereas I trust the Chachamim - yes, I have emunas chachamim! 1/2

Comment: 2/2 And one who doesn't, and thinks they can go beat their own path, does not fully believe in Hashem, as they are denying that our gedolim, who have daas Torah, can have a final say. They want to bring the Torah closer to themselves, not themselves closer to the Torah. "How can we bring anyone closer to the Torah if we don't ourselves believe it says anything we can read?" - That is a stupid question, straight up. Why can't one bring someone closer to the Torah without being a Maskil? "[I feel that RSR Hirsch takes this obligation very seriously.]" - I don't know much about the shittas of

Comment: 3/2 Reb Shamshon Rephael Hirsch, but I know he was a gadol, and would never, chas veshalom, agree with what you are saying. Your feeling is just that - a feeling. And I get a feeling you are more than a shtickel maskil.

Comment: I don't ask anyone to accept my impression of RSR Hirsch. Of course not. But that is my impression.

Comment: "Chas veshalom! Are you insinuating that Chazal is, chas veshalom, seperate from the Torah?!" Absolutely not. I think they are reading it right. It is your reading that I'm complaining about. You started by saying that "it looks bad", but Chazal say it's good. No! We need to think about it ourselves until we can understand where Chazal are coming from, why they saw the Torah the way they do. You are skipping that step. Our job is to connect the words of Chazal to the words of the Torah.

Comment: What does this has to do with being a Maskil - which I am not? This has to do with trusting Chazal enough to believe that if I really work hard on understanding the Torah, their words will help guide me to do it, and that in the end I can know why they read the Torah the way they did. Again, you are skipping that step, and a beginner would be justified in wondering why he would trust Chazal when he is dealing with the actual written words and you are not.

Comment: Btw, just saw a Ramban on last week's parsha, https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.9?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=he "I don't know the reason for our old forefather - how is it appropriate for him to whine to the king?" Something like that. If that question were posted here, you would tell him he's way out of line. But Mikraos Gedolos has that thousands of times. The Ramban just wants to understand.

Comment: "Are 5 year old unable to be wrong?" Sure they are. Adults can be wrong too. But the Chumash is taught to five year olds, because five year olds can understand it on their level. This is an amazing thing about the Chumash; it isn't true of anything else I know of. It's written *simply*. Compare to Yeshaya or anything else. Hashem put every level into the Chumash and all of them are true. I don't know how that is possible but it is so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141693/discussion-between-michoelr-and-kovy-jacob).

Answer (score 0):

From the outset, Yosef explained that the purpose of the dream was to inform Pharaoh of what is about to happen. The idea being that Pharaoh should know what to do. In fact, The [Ohr Hachaim Hakadosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.16a.4?lang=he) uses this to explain why Yosef saw fit to advise the king when he wasn't asked to do so. Moreover, continues the Ohr Hachaim, the advice is alluded to in the dream as well, where it shows the famished cows/stalks eating the fuller ones.

Another point is that in general when a natural disaster hits it is not necessarily meant to be seen as a direct message, but rather we can use it to confirm, or reaffirm, fear of Hashem. In this vain the [Gemara in Brachos](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.59a.12?lang=he) tells us that thunder was created in order to straighten out the heart (to remind us of the might of Hashem).

The Dor Haflaga was sinful in taking a clearly prophesied and clearly non-natural event out of its prophecy context and reinterpreting it as a natural occurrence. And they all knew that it wasn't the case. That would be similar to the Egyptians reacting to the Makkos as if it were a natural occurrence. But a famine is just like a hurricane.